# Agregar valores a diccionario dependiendo su coordenada

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo "n" numeros, tengo que crear un diccionario (el cual n sera su largo y ancho sera i/n) para formar un diccionario.

Digamos que n es = a 4, entonces:

```
  y  0.25  0.5  0.75                 
0.25
0.5
0.75

# para generar este diccionario
data = {"y/x": []}
for i in range(n):
    data["y/x"].append(i/n)
    data[i/n] = []
```

Una vez generado el diccionario tengo una lista (que siempre sera par), se tiene que generar hasta N/2 pares.

```
Lista dada
nums = [0.60365, 0.83799, 0.32960, 0.19322, 0.11220,
        0.37751, 0.88492, 0.30934, 0.22888, 0.78212]
```

Coordenadas de N-1

```
coord = [(0.60365, 0.83799), (0.3296, 0.19322), (0.1122, 0.37751), (0.88492, 0.30934), (0.22888, 0.78212)]
```

Despues, **¿Como puedo colocar la cantidad de pares que estan dentro de los intervalos del diccionario?** De tal manera que quede de la siguiente manera?**

```
    y/x      0 ->0.25   .25 -> .5   .5 -> .75   .75 -> 1
 0  -> 0.25     1            1          0            0
.25 -> .5       1            2          0            1
.5  -> .75      0            0          0            1
.75 -> 1        0            1          1            0
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que lo primero que puedes hacer es una función que te devuelva la posición `x` e `y` del `df` en la que los elementos de cada tupla deberían estar:

```
def condiciones(valor):
    if valor < 0.25:
        return 0
    elif valor < 0.5:
        return 1
    elif valor < 0.75:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3


posiciones = [(condiciones(x), condiciones(y)) for (x, y) in coord]
```

Esto devolvería `[(3, 4), (2, 1), (1, 2), (4, 2), (1, 4)]`

luego creamos un `df` con todo ceros:

```
tramos = ['0 ->0.25', '0.25 ->0.5', '0.5 ->0.75', '0.75 ->1']

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=tramos, columns=tramos)
```

Ya solamente hay que recorrer las lista con las tuplas que tienen las posiciones e ir sumando 1 en cada posición:

```
for x, y in posiciones:
    df.iloc[y, x] += 1
```

El código completo de ejemplo sería este:

```
import pandas as pd

coord = [(0.60365, 0.83799), (0.3296, 0.19322), (0.21688, 0.85312), (0.1122, 0.37751),
         (0.88492, 0.30934), (0.22888, 0.78212)]

def condiciones(valor):
    if valor < 0.25:
        return 0
    elif valor < 0.5:
        return 1
    elif valor < 0.75:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

posiciones = [(condiciones(x), condiciones(y)) for (x, y) in coord]
tramos = ['0 ->0.25', '0.25 ->0.5', '0.5 ->0.75', '0.75 ->1']

df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=tramos, columns=tramos)

for x, y in posiciones:
    df.iloc[y, x] += 1

print(df)
```

Esto nos devolvería:

```
            0 ->0.25  0.25 ->0.5  0.5 ->0.75  0.75 ->1
0 ->0.25           0           1           0         0
0.25 ->0.5         1           0           0         1
0.5 ->0.75         0           0           0         0
0.75 ->1           2           0           1         0
```